# After installation of NGenuity keyboard software the media keys do not work anymore

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, media-keys

I bought a new keyboard **HyperX Alloy FPS RGB** and my **media keys don't work**. But always one after the other. I connected the keyboard to my freshly installed Windows. On a USB port which sits directly on the motherboard. **Everything works fine**, even the media keys. I can do louder, quieter and so on. **But as soon as I install the software** for my keyboard **the media keys don't work** anymore. When I then stop and close the suite (latest version of HyperX NGenuity) which manages my keyboard, unplug my keyboard and reinsert it. Everything works again! If I start NGenuity again, the media keys are deactivated again as soon as the software is loaded.

---

What I have tried so far:

1. i don't have the Google Music extension in Google Chrome
2. human interface is active and set to automatic
3. i have the latest software from NGenuity as well as the drivers for my keyboard in the Device Manager
4. my Bios has no entry for the function of the FN key (Media keys with or without FN key)
5. i have completely reinstalled Windows 10, including deleting my data
6. keyboard reset to factory setting by FN + ESC until keyboard flashes

---

I have the feeling that windows is messing something with the drivers. I'm not so windows affine that I could locate the problem. I hope someone has an idea.

Comment: I just called customer support. They asked me to connect the keyboard to another PC/laptop. The media keys also worked on my laptop + NGenuity. After that I connected the keyboard to my tower again and now it works wonderfully there too. I guess the internal memory of the keyboard saved something wrong. I'll test another week now, if everything works fine I'll write an answer to this thread.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the solution with the laptop either. I have now returned the keyboard and bought one from another brand. More than a weekend I don't want to invest the search of an error that shouldn't be present by default. I'm now assuming that the keyboard software NGenuity is not 100% compatible with Windows 10, because the new keyboard software runs without problems. Too bad because I found the keyboard of HyperX very appealing and the software was very very personalizable.